# Unable to create listview using metadata api on Salesforce

Tags: soap, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am new to Salesforce metadata api. I want to create a listview of contacts on Salesforce using metadata api.

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:met="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <soap:Header>
      <met:AllOrNoneHeader>
         <met:allOrNone>false</met:allOrNone>
      </met:AllOrNoneHeader>
      <met:CallOptions>
         <met:client>https://xyz.salesforce.com</met:client>
      </met:CallOptions>
      <met:SessionHeader>
         <met:sessionId>xyz</met:sessionId>
      </met:SessionHeader>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <met:createMetadata>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <met:metadata>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <met:fullName>TESTVIEW__c</met:fullName>
         </met:metadata>
      </met:createMetadata>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am getting

```
[
    {
        "errorCode": "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED",
        "message": "HTTP Method 'POST' not allowed. Allowed are HEAD,GET"
    }
]
```

The endpoint I use is:

https://xyz.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Contact/listviews

I updated to SOAP endpoint:

`https://xyz-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/51.0/1112312DRED21`

Now I am getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>content-type of the request should be text/xml</faultstring>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I guess I am one step closer. Is the payload valid for creation of contact listview?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a Metadata API deployment by making a POST to the REST API endpoint.

If you want to use a REST endpoint, use the [REST deployRequest endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_rest_deploy.htm). If you want to use the SOAP [`createMetadata()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_createMetadata.htm) call to which your payload appears to be oriented, you need to use the [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickstart.htm).